# Set up opt-in Highcharts Alerts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like to setup a method for sending users an alert via email if a critical value is crossed in highcharts (I'd also like them to have to opt in to this feature rather than it being compulsory). Is there any built in functionality for this? Could anyone recommend the best way to go about solving this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have a reaction to what is happening on the chart, you need to connect to [chart.events](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events). There you will be able to plug in an external function that will send an email, in Higcharts there is no such option built in.

In this case use [event render](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render) fire after each redraw, as your data changes dynamically.

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      render: function() {
        let data = this.series[0].data;

        data.forEach(function(point) {
          console.log(point.y);
          if (point.y > 40) {
            window.alert("you have point above 40");
          }
        })

      }
    },
  },
```

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jpcz7xu2/1/